# Triviality of complexified tangent bundle of spheres

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

What is known on the triviality of the complexified tangent bundle of the spheres? Are they always trivial?

Here is my progress. If we are just looking at any rank n complex vector bundle, then this would correspond to looking at $S^n \to BU(n)$ or equivalently $\pi_n(BU(n)) \cong \pi_{n-1}(U(n)) \cong \pi_{n-1}(U(n-1))$. However $\pi_{n-1}(U(n-1))$ can still be nonzero for even n as it alternates between 0 and $\mathbb{Z}$. So we are left with even dimensional spheres. Of course this does not use that it is the tangent bundle (not any other complex rank n vector bundle), but I could not figure out how to integrate this in the argument. Of course in the cases where tangent bundle of sphere is parallelizable (dim=1,3 and 7), the complexification will also be trivial, but these are already covered by above argument.

When $n=2$, [Triviality of complexified tangent bundle of a closed surface](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3164934/triviality-of-complexified-tangent-bundle-of-a-closed-surface?rq=1) shows that complexification is trivial.  What about even dimensional spheres for $2n \geq 4$?

Here is an attempt with characteristic classes: $TS^n \oplus \epsilon_{S^n}^1\cong TS^n \oplus \nu=\epsilon_{S^n}^{n+1}$ where $\nu$ stands for the trivial normal bundle, now we can look at Pontrjagin classes of $TS^n$, those are obtained after complexifying the tangent bundle hence may carry information on nontriviality of complexified tangent bundle. However $p(TS^n)=p(TS^n \oplus \epsilon_{S^n}^1)=p(\epsilon_{S^n}^{n+1})$ by the stable property of Pontrjagin classes hence we do not get any nontrivial info.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed the complexified tangent bundle of the sphere $TS^n \otimes \mathbb{C}$ is always trivial. To prove this consider the commutative diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\pi_n(BO(n)) @>{i_*}>> \pi_n(BO(n+1))\\
@VV{\sigma_*}V @VV{\sigma_*}V\\
\pi_n(BU(n)) @>{i_*}>{\cong}> \pi_n(BU(n+1))
\end{CD}
where the vertical maps are induced by complexification and the horizontal maps are induced by Whitney sum with a trivial (respectively real and complex) line bundle. Let $\tau$ be the classifying map of the tangent bundle $TS^n$. Since $TS^n \oplus \varepsilon^1 \cong \varepsilon^{n+1}$ then $i_*(\tau) = 0$ thus $\sigma_*(i_*(\tau)) = 0$. Since the diagram is commutative then $ i_*(\sigma_*(\tau)) = 0$. However, as indicated on the diagram the latter map is an isomorphism thus $\sigma_*(\tau)=0$.